# get selected checkboxlist list items value

Tags: jquery, asp.net, checkboxlist

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            var values = '';

            $('#MainContent_ddl input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function () {
                debugger;
                alert('hi');
                if (values.length == 0) {
                    values = this.parent().attr('Value');
                }
                else {
                    values += "," + $('label[for=' + this.id + ']').html();
                }
            });
            alert(values);
            return false;

        });
```

The above code I am trying to get the currently selected checkboxlist items value which I have defined as follows

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="ddl" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"
            OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl_SelectedIndexChanged"
            Style="padding-top: 150px;">

            <asp:ListItem Text="ABC" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="DEF" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="GHI" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="JKL" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>

        </asp:CheckBoxList>

<asp:HiddenField ID="hd" runat="server" />
```

Rendered checkboxlist

```
<tr>
        <td><input id="MainContent_ddl_0" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainContent$ddl$0" onclick="javascript:setTimeout(&#39;__doPostBack(\&#39;ctl00$MainContent$ddl$0\&#39;,\&#39;\&#39;)&#39;, 0)" value="0" /><label for="MainContent_ddl_0">ABC</label></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td><input id="MainContent_ddl_1" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainContent$ddl$1" onclick="javascript:setTimeout(&#39;__doPostBack(\&#39;ctl00$MainContent$ddl$1\&#39;,\&#39;\&#39;)&#39;, 0)" value="1" /><label for="MainContent_ddl_1">DEF</label></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td><input id="MainContent_ddl_2" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainContent$ddl$2" onclick="javascript:setTimeout(&#39;__doPostBack(\&#39;ctl00$MainContent$ddl$2\&#39;,\&#39;\&#39;)&#39;, 0)" value="2" /><label for="MainContent_ddl_2">GHI</label></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td><input id="MainContent_ddl_3" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainContent$ddl$3" onclick="javascript:setTimeout(&#39;__doPostBack(\&#39;ctl00$MainContent$ddl$3\&#39;,\&#39;\&#39;)&#39;, 0)" value="3" /><label for="MainContent_ddl_3">JKL</label></td>
    </tr>
```

How can I get the currently selected value and store it in a hidden field. Where Am I going wrong.

Comment: please please please please add the rendered html than server side coding

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per your statement:
*I am trying to get the currently selected checkboxlist items value*

Try this

```
values = $(this).val()
```

or:

```
values = this.value;
```

You can do something like this:

```js
    var value;

    $('input[type=checkbox]').change(function () {
        if(this.checked){
           value = this.value; // put the value of checked only
        }
        $('p').text(value);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='checkbox' value='0' />
<input type='checkbox' value='1' />
<input type='checkbox' value='2' />
<input type='checkbox' value='3' />
<input type='checkbox' value='4' />
<p></p>
```

Because in your script you intialized your var with a `""` blank string value to all the checked input type checkboxes, so value gets concatenated with the previous values.

Instead you have to use this in `.change()` event and check if element is checked if true then update the var value with the current clicked element value and send it to the backend code.

Comment: Now the problem is, if I check the 2nd checkbox, it gives me value of 1st chk box and then the 2nd checkbox. I want the currently selected checkbox list value. How can i do that.

Comment: What exactly you want to do? can you elaborate more because there may be a better approach to do.

Comment: I have a checkboxlist with some values. When I select a checkboxlist item I get data using its id from DB. Now when I select the 2nd checkboxlist item , I want only want that 2nd checkboxlist item's value so that I can take that value and go to DB and fetch the data and append it to the gridview with previous checkboxlist item's data.

Comment: Because in your script you intialized your var with a `""` blank string value to all the checked value gets concatenated with the previous values. Instead you have to use this in `.change()` event and check if element is checked if true then update the var value with the current clicked element value and send it to the backend code.

Comment: can u pls provide me with the code. I am failry new to using jquery and  stuff. I'll be thankful.

Comment: You can check to see the snippet added in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

`this` is a javascript object.

in order to use jquery methods you should convert it to jquery object

replace `this` with `$(this)` and then run it.

Comment: _this is a javascript object._  No it's a dom node while `$(this)` is a jQuery wrapper, `$()` its a jQuery wrapper which is used to wrap the dom nodes to create a jQuery selector.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 $('input[type=checkbox][id^="MainContent_ddl_"]:checked').each(function (index,item) {   
     if (values.length == 0) {
        values = $(item).val();           
     }
     else {
        values += "," + $(item).val();
     }
 });
 alert(values);
```

[Click here to see demo](http://jsfiddle.net/stackmanoj/subLp9a9/)

Comment: You should use controlName.ClientID instead of the wildcard match on id.